React app offline page render on browser reload
I have a React app that uses the react-use-is-online npm package to detect when the browser is online or offline. The package works as expected for displaying online/offline messages while navigating between online and offline states. However, when I refresh the page while offline, the app doesn’t load, and the browser shows its default "No Internet" error page.
I want my app to load and display a custom offline message when refreshed without an internet connection, just like YouTube does. How can I achieve this?
Here’s a minimal reproducible example of my code on https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/q6l8jp Link to your project.

Did you check the Service Workers?

been trying that for hours , same result

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

I resolved this issue using a service worker and PWA setup. This allows the app to display a custom offline message, even when the browser is refreshed without an internet connection. Here's how it works:
Service Worker & PWA:
The service worker caches essential files and a custom offline page, so it can serve this content when the user is offline.
Note that service workers only function in production build environments, so this may not work during local development.
Error Handling:
Implement an error boundary to catch JavaScript errors and display a fallback UI.
Ensure all critical resources and the custom offline page are cached. Otherwise, if the requested page isn't cached, the default "no internet" page will still appear.
Result: With this setup, the app displays a custom offline message instead of the browser's default offline page, similar to how YouTube handles offline scenarios.

enter image description here
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/AJPlEDe8.png
I tried to load https://www.youtube.com/ in an offline state, and saw that it was a static resource returned via service worker, which means that offline caching was done, I guess, to give the user a better experience, which should belong to the pwa level.
Your website is able to display customized information during normal use with the network turned off, because the required resources have already been downloaded and the logic is executing normally.
If you try to refresh your website with the network closed, and request resources without offline caching and disconnected from the network, it's impossible to request any content, let alone execute your judgment logic!

Make sure your answer is well-formatted and explains how to solve the problem.
